# How to design a POS bill in java?

Tags: java, java-print

I'm designing a java application to a pharmacy and I wanted to print a bill for their customers. I tried using `jasper` reports but I was unable to design it properly.

I have created 2 `jTables` to display items in stock and another to display the bill. Bellow the bill table 2 `jLables` and 1 `jTextField` used to show the total, balance and received amounts. I wanted to print the details in the bill table and values in 2 `jLabels` and `jTextField` when I click the "Pay" button. I want to design it like this [POS bill](https://www.google.lk/search?q=pos%20bill&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jHxIVJ2yNoehmgWzrIGQAw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=hgF0BiaplJ1BMM%253A%3B0wlnxt-vOwJRYM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tallysolutions.com%252Fwebsite%252FCHM%252FTallyERP9%252F04_ADVANCED_FEATURES_IN_TALLY%252F02_Advanced_Inventory_Features_in_Tally%252FPoint_of_Sale%252F10_Printing_a_POS_Invoice_2.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tallysolutions.com%252Fwebsite%252FCHM%252FTallyERP9%252F04_ADVANCED_FEATURES_IN_TALLY%252F02_Advanced_Inventory_Features_in_Tally%252FPoint_of_Sale%252FPrinting_a_POS_Invoice.htm%3B265%3B436)

How to design and print a bill like this in java? How to change the page size?

I'm using `netbeans` to develop.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: You can find more related things on Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Jasper Report Studio or Netbeans plugin to create your bill. Before start to work with Jasper it is better to go through a jasper related document or online tutorial.

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_fields.htm 
>   https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial
>   https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/designing-report-jaspersoft-studio

You don not need to create a separate table to keep stock and bill separately.I think it is better to keep all records in one jTable.Then you can get that jTabel as a data source into the Jasper Report .You can pass total, balance and amount values as parameters into the jasper report and place those values in the correct place of the bill

If you use the Jasper Report studio or netbeans plugin, right click on the report icon in the "Outline" window to get the page setup menu

Good Luck !!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the links!

can you please tell me how to adjust the page size?
i want to print it using a pos bill printer; I think length of the page is depending on no.of items  so what about the width?

Comment: According to your requirement, you have to specify the width of the page. Width of the page can be change easily. You can find the page setup by right clicking on the page icon in the "Outline" window. Otherwise you can do it by configuring the report xml.